# Resampling with entries with same code (ID)

Tags: r, resampling

In `R`, I'm trying to resample my dataset.

The database `A` includes some codes in the first column (integer) and characteristics of each row as follows:

`A <- as.matrix(cbind(floor(runif(1000, 1,101)), matrix(rexp(20000, rate=.1), ncol=20) ))`

Some codes are repeated in the first column.

I want to resample randomly codes from the first column and create a new matrix or dataframe such that for each entry in the resampled code vector it gives me the right hand side. If there are more vectors with the same resampled code it should include both. Also, if I'm resampling the same code twice, all rows in A with the same resample code should appear twice.

---EDIT---

The resampling is done with replacement. So far what I did is:

```
res <- resample(unique(A[,1]), size = length(unique(A[,1])) , replace = TRUE, prob= NULL) 
A.new <- A[which(A[,1] %in% res),]
```

however, assume that two lines in `A` have the same code (say 2), and that the vector `res` selects `2` 4 times. In `A.new` I will only have 2 twice (because there are two lines coded as `2` in `A[,1]`), instead that having these two lines repeated 4 times

Comment: The desired output is not clear.  Are you trying to sample with replacement?  Are you trying to include multiple rows that share a common first column?

Comment: @manotheshark Thank you. I added some more explanation.

Comment: @lmo Thank you, I added what I did so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it like this:

```
A.new = sapply(res, function(x) A[A[,1] == x, ])
A.new = do.call(rbind, A.new)
```

The first line makes a list of matrices in which each value of `res` creates a list item that is the subset of `A` for which the 1st column equals that value of `res`.  If `res` contains the same number more than once, a matrix will be created for each occurrence of that value.

The 2nd line uses `rbind` to condense this list into a single matrix

Comment: Hi, that seems the way to go, but I can't get it to work. Have you tried it on your end? Thank you

Comment: Yes, tested, and it worked for me.  There was one typo in your code, where you had `resample`, it should have been `sample`. Was that your issue?

Comment: Thanks for that, though I do not have very clear the difference between `sample` and `resample`. Your code works fine on my data with `lapply`, instead of `sapply`! Thank you